# If two norms on an infinite dimentional vector space generate the same completion (generates two isomorphic banach spaces) are they equivalent?

Tags: functional-analysis

If two norms on an infinite dimensional vector space X make the same completion(the clousure of the vector space with respect to two norms are the same ) are they equivalent norm ? If not would you give me a counter example ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "make the same completion"?

Comment: I guess he means "closure". I kind of understand that question - do you mean for every subset of your given vector space?

Comment: I would assume by completion he means the metric space completion.

Comment: @89701407 When you say the same do you mean isomorphic as vector spaces or isomorphic as banach spaces?

Comment: isomorphic as banach spaces